# Power BI service export of images has changed?

Tags: powerbi, visualization

We have a Power BI report using the Image Grid visualisation which we export as a pdf from the online Power BI service. As of last week this no longer works with a 'This visual does not support exporting' message.

Exporting from the desktop pbix still works fine. Can anyone explain this recent behaviour change and suggest an alternative visual that may work? Image by cloudscope does not, while Image Pro by Cloudscope will not accept an image via http/https.

Thanks for reading and in advance for any input.